# Python cipher encrypt length multiples of 16: non-ascii characters

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data which contains non-ascii characters as follows:

```
data = '測試'  # These are non-ascii characters

cipher = AES.new(someKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
code = data.rjust(16)  # Length must be multiples of 16
print(len(code))
encrypted = cipher.encrypt(code)
```

Since `data` contains non-ascii characters, `cipher.encrypt()` complains that the string is not of length 16:

```
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Encryption algorithms operate on sequences of bits, raw data, not strings.  The non-ascii characters are not relevant here.  Use a padding scheme like PKCS#7 on the **decoded bytes** of your string.

Comment: @LukePark I think you mean encoded bytes. Eg, `data.encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: Is this for a serious program that actually needs security? If so, why are you using ECB?

Comment: @PM2Ring Nope, I meant the decoded bytes, you don't pad a string here.

Comment: @PM2Ring I need to send the encrypted "reset password" link to the user who forgot his/her password. Is my solution appropriate? Or you have a better solution?

Comment: According to Luke, the following works: `code = bytes(data.encode('utf-8')).rjust(16)`

Comment: No, according to Luke, you should use PKCS#7 to pad those bytes, not simple padding with spaces.

Comment: My problem is only about converting the string to bytes, not the encryption algorithm. BTW, is PKCS#7 better than Crypto cipher AES?

Comment: I'm no security expert, but I know that ECB mode is generally not safe, and ECB-encoded data can be "cracked" in certain situations, for example, [see here](https://www.cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/12). How does the user use that "reset password" link? Do they need to decrypt it? If so, how do they get the key?

Comment: [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) is merely a padding protocol used by various encryption schemes, including AES.

Comment: are you using the cryptography library? I would use the cryptography library